# I cant change value of Input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, calculator

I want to create `Javascript` simple calculator, I want to change `<input>` tag's value on click, I used this

```
document.getElementById('input').value = "1"
```

But it types once **1** so I can't type **11** or **111**. What is problem? Can you help me?

Comment: can u share the full code?

Comment: try document.getElementById('input').value = document.getElementById('input').value+"1";

Comment: thanks for help, it works

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's the correct answer as OP's code wasn't provided...

```js
var el = document.getElementById('input');
el.value = 1;

var button = document.getElementById('button')

button.onclick = function() {
 
  el.value = parseInt(el.value) + 1;

}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" name="name" value="">

<button id="button">Add 1!</button>
```

On button click, the function will retrieve the value from the input box, convert it to integer and then add 1.

If that's not the answer you were looking for, let me know.

EDIT: Just to clarify.
I have used `parseInt()` to convert to integer. This way if el.value = 1
The result will be **2**. However if I don't use `parseInt()` I would get a concatenation instead of an operation and el.value + 1 would do **11**, el.value being a string.

Comment: it not the answer that I looking, I want to add "1" at every push, ex. "1" "11" "111"

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the value of that field as

```
var val = document.getElementById('input').value;
```

Then Add a value and show in it as

```
document.getElementById('input').value = val + 1;
```

Here is a complete Running code:

```js
function function_name (argument) {
  var val = document.getElementById('input').value;   
   document.getElementById('input').value = val + 1;
 }
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" name="name" value="">
    <button id="button" onclick="function_name()">Press 1!</button>
```

Comment: @Y. Vahe you accepted my answer when you asked this question and the answer is according to what you want in question. So, why you mark this as unaccepted later. Can I know the reason?